# how to check if a class exist in a link?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check a condition where if a link contain "`current`" class then I need to perform some action. Links have a custom attribute "`data-step"`.

I need to perform some action when `data-step="3"` will contain a class current.

The links are here:

```
<a href="#" data-step="1" class="multistep_section">login</a>
<a href="#" data-step="2" class="multistep_section">billing address</a>
<a href="#" data-step="3" class="current multistep_section">Shipping Address</a>
<a href="#" data-step="4" class="multistep_section">payment</a>
<a href="#" data-step="5" class="multistep_section">order review</a>
```

class current is variable and changed as per the steps. I need to do some action in jquery or javascript only when `data-step="3"` contains class "current"

Any suggestion are welcome

Comment: Do you want to do this when the link is clicked on?

Comment: No not on click only to check if a class exist

Comment: can you tell me how to know which data step have current class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited response based on posters feedback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('a[data-step=3]').hasClass('current')){
         // Current class exists on data-step 3  
    }
});
```

and with plain JS:

```
(function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-step]');
    var targetElement;

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-step') == 3){
             targetElement = elements[i];    
        }
    }

    if (targetElement.classList.contains('current')){
        alert("Has current class");   
    }
})();
```

See plain JS example: http://jsfiddle.net/19tmab49/4/

Comment: I need both when data-step has 3 value and a class current.

Comment: Then this is the way to go :) the full code can be seen on here: http://jsfiddle.net/19tmab49/

Comment: if i dont want on click I just want to check simply then please I am poor with jquery and javascript

Comment: This will check if it exists once the page is loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/19tmab49/2/ see updated response as well

Comment: yes this is what I actually what I want but in javascript. pLease

Comment: Added plain JS example to answer

Comment: Was this the correct answer? if so please mark it as such

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var class_name = "current";
  
  // if element is contained in an array (function)
  function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var tempLink = links[i]; // represents each links
    var dataStep_value = tempLink.getAttribute("data-step"); // getting "data-step" value
 
    var classes = tempLink.className.split(" ");
      
    if (isInArray(class_name, classes)) {
      // current is in array, do whatever you need to 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-step="1" class="multistep_section">login</a>
<a href="#" data-step="2" class="multistep_section">billing address</a>
<a href="#" data-step="3" class="current multistep_section">Shipping Address</a>
<a href="#" data-step="4" class="multistep_section">payment</a>
<a href="#" data-step="5" class="multistep_section">order review</a>
```

You will not see the result of this function instead of adding an alert in the area I commented. This script check the `data-step` attribute, and check another time for the one that are set to "3" if they contain the class "current" (variable `class_name`).